# Add item in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a Activity that's creating a Check list, if I close the activity with back Button the list is saved in a Database.

The list from the Database is used as the MainActivity content.

**This is how my app will look:**

[image]

If I press the <kbd>List Item</kbd> button, a new element should be added to the list. How can I add and sisplay a new Item (Layout with Checkbox and EditText)?

Do I need an Adapter? I don't want the 'list item' part repeated.

[image]

That looks so after i press 4 times

Comment: i have edit my Post.. i dont have an adapter because i dont know how i should begin

Comment: i am confused ad this point.. i know that i need an adapter, but if i have an String array i add the string of them in the TextView.. know i dont have an String ... i have an layout that must add? where ist my Problem, i am so confused

Comment: after you type in the text view you either need a button or a text watcher to trigger an event... when that event happens you need to add your string to  the text in your adapter and then notify changes

Comment: Ok but how did i become a new Line after i press the List item button ?

Comment: I've added an answer which should give you everything you need to get started, doesnt sound like you need a custom adapter, just use an array adaoter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Activity**

```
private ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
```

**onCreate**

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
List<String> initialList = new ArrayList<String>(); //load these 
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.id.text1, initialList)
lv.setadapter(mAdapter);
```

**When the event happens**

```
mAdapter.add(newString);
```

The add method in ArrayAdpater will automatically take care of the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call for you and update the display.

**TextWatcher** *you might not need this part, it's if you want the text added as soon as the text is changed which your question seems to indicate - that is risky because you might get partial entries, so i recommend a <kbd>done</kbd> button instead, in which case you just do the `afterTextChanged` stuff in the `onClick` method.*

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text); 
editText .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            //TODO: check it isnt emtpy 
            String text = arg0.getText().toString();
            mAdapter.add(text); 

            //Hide the add item views again
            arg0.setText("");
            arg0.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) { /*nothing*/ }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) { /*nothing*/ }


 });
```

Comment: thats helpful thanks. i try to make that. I reedited my Answer with a new screenshot. It your solution seems like that?

Comment: Yes, my example is for the listenintrag part, but you can use the TextWatcher part on each item to save changes that are made to existing items if that's what the screenshot should show (if you need help with that its a separate question)

Comment: The Screenshot i have new edited.. was my Problem.. after i have try to make the textWatcher or Button or something.. i can add Strings for my adapter... but how can i add a Layout, or a new EditText plus checkbox after i press the button Listeneintrag ... the content was empty and the user get start to make a new Task and so on

Comment: Then you need to make a custom layout with all the things you want on each item and supply that when you call 'new ArrayAdapter'

Answer (score 0):

You can add plus button in your list as footerview as your image then new item add in your arraylist by the action(onClicklistener) of footer view button then call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: How should my adapter look? I have the same idea, but how can i add this view in the list ? i must inflate the layout from new Item and add this in my adapter ?

Comment: list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.listView);
   View footerView  =((LayoutInflater)    getApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);